# How can I create a slime that can be used as a soccer ball in Minecraft 1.16.5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been searching around YouTube and websites trying to find a command for slime that can be used as a soccer ball. I've been trying to figure out a way to use the slime, like hit it, knock it around, etc. I've also tried the old command that someone had asked years ago about this too. (Didn't work.)

Are we still able to find a way to do this? Please let me know if you've got a command for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an item with knockback to knock it around, you can easily get such an item from the amazing command generator at mcstacker.net. you could use command blocks with /data to get a better result, but it is a lot of work.

For example:

`/give @p cod{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:5s}]} 1`

Give the slime regeneration so it doesn't die:

`/effect give @e[type=slime,distance=..3,limit=1] regeneration 1000000 255`